# NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'inline'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins to a GCP Instance Group. To do so, I'm told I must run this pipeline script (parameters omitted).

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Triger CloudBuild..') {
      steps {
        googleCloudBuild credentialsId: '<ENTER-YOUR-CREDS-ID>' , request: inline('''steps:
        # Creating a golden image
        - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
          id: create-golden-image
          args:
          - beta
          - compute
          - images
          - create                                                                                 
          - <ENTER-NEW-IMAGE-NAME>
          - --source-disk=<ENTER-YOUR-VM-SOURCEDISK-NAME>
          - --source-disk-zone=<ENTER-YOUR-SOURCE-DISK-ZONE>
          - --project=<ENTER-YOUR-PROJECT-ID>
          - --force
        #Creating a new instance template
        - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
          id: create-instance-template
          args:
          - beta
          - compute
          - instance-templates
          - create
          - <ENTER-YOUR-NEW-TEMPLATE-NAME>
          - --subnet=projects/<ENTER-YOUR-PROJECT-ID>/regions/<ENTER-YOUR-REGION-NAME>/subnetworks/<ENTER-YOUR-SUBNET-NAME>
          - --no-address
          - --image-project=<ENTER-YOUR-PROJECT-ID>
          - --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE
          - --service-account=<ENTER-YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-NAME>
          - --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
          - --region=<ENTER-REGION-NAME>
          - --tags=mig-rolling-update
          - --image=<ENTER-NEW-IMAGE-NAME>
          - --boot-disk-size=<ENTER-BOOT-DISK-SIZE>
          - --boot-disk-type=<ENTER-DISK-SIZE>
          - --boot-disk-device-name=<ENTER-BOOT-DISK-NAME>
          - --project=<ENTER-YOUR-PROJECT-ID>
        #Make sure that our MIG is stable before update
        - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
          id: wait-until-stable
          args:
          - beta
          - compute
          - instance-groups
          - managed
          - wait-until
          - <ENTER-YOUR-MIG-NAME>
          - --stable
          - --project=<ENTER-YOUR-PROJECT-ID>
          - --zone=<ENTER-YOUR-ZONE-NAME>
        #Updating the MIG with new instance template
        - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
          id: updating-mig
          args:
          - beta
          - compute
          - instance-groups
          - managed
          - rolling-action
          - start-update
          - <ENTER-YOUR-MIG-NAME>
          - --version=template=<ENTER-YOUR-TEMPLATE-NAME>
          - --type=proactive
          - --zone=<ENTER-YOUR-ZONE-NAME>
          - --project=<ENTER-YOUR-PROJECT-ID>''')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'inline' found among
> steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir,
> downstreamBuilds, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool,
> error, fileExists, findBuildScans, getContext, git, input, isUnix,
> junit, library, libraryResource, load, lock, mail, milestone, node,
> parallel, powershell, properties, publishChecks, publishHTML, pwd,
> pwsh, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep,
> stage, stash, step, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive,
> unstable, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitForBuild,
> waitUntil, warnError, withChecks, withContext, withCredentials,
> withEnv, withGradle, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols
> [GitUsernamePassword, agent, all, allBranchesSame, allOf, always, ant,
> antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken,
> apiTokenProperty, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager,
> assembla, authorInChangelog, authorizationMatrix, batchFile,
> bitbucket, bitbucketServer, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects,
> brokenTestsSuspects, browser, buildButton, buildDiscarder,
> buildDiscarders, buildRetention, buildSingleRevisionOnly, buildUser,
> buildingTag, builtInNode, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate,
> cgit, changeRequest, changelog, changelogBase, changelogToBranch,
> changeset, checkoutOption, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice,
> choiceParam, cleanAfterCheckout, cleanBeforeCheckout, cleanWs, clock,
> cloneOption, command, contributor, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits,
> defaultDisplayUrlProvider, defaultFolderConfiguration, defaultView,
> demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableRestartFromStage,
> disableResume, discoverOtherRefs, discoverOtherRefsTrait, downstream,
> dumb, durabilityHint, email-ext, envVars, envVarsFilter, environment,
> equals, experimentalFlags, expression, extendedEmailPublisher, file,
> fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, fingerprints, fisheye, frameOptions,
> freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, gitBranchDiscovery,
> gitHooks, gitHubBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchHeadAuthority,
> gitHubExcludeArchivedRepositories, gitHubExcludeForkedRepositories,
> gitHubExcludePrivateRepositories, gitHubExcludePublicRepositories,
> gitHubForkDiscovery, gitHubIgnoreDraftPullRequestFilter,
> gitHubPullRequestDiscovery, gitHubSshCheckout, gitHubTagDiscovery,
> gitHubTopicsFilter, gitHubTrustContributors, gitHubTrustEveryone,
> gitHubTrustNobody, gitHubTrustPermissions, gitLab, gitList, gitSCM,
> gitTagDiscovery, gitTool, gitUsernamePassword, gitWeb, gitblit,
> github, githubProjectProperty, githubPush, gitiles, gogs, gradle,
> group, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink,
> hyperlinkToModels, ignoreOnPush, inbound, inheriting,
> inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, jdk, jdkInstaller,
> jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobBuildDiscarder, jobName,
> junitTestResultStorage, kiln, label, lastDuration, lastFailure,
> lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM,
> lfs, list, local, localBranch, localBranchTrait, locale, location,
> logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, mailer, masterBuild, maven,
> maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenGlobalConfig, mavenMojos,
> mavenWarnings, modernSCM, multiBranchProjectDisplayNaming,
> multibranch, myView, namedBranchesDifferent, node, nodeProperties,
> nonInheriting, none, nonresumable, not, organizationFolder,
> overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast,
> parameters, password, pattern, perBuildTag, permanent, phabricator,
> pipeline, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM,
> preserveStashes, previous, priorityStrategy, projectNamingStrategy,
> proxy, pruneStaleBranch, pruneStaleTag, pruneTags,
> queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimit, rateLimitBuilds,
> recipients, redmine, refSpecs, remoteName, requestor, resourceRoot,
> retainOnlyVariables, rhodeCode, run, runParam, sSHLauncher, schedule,
> scmGit, scmRetryCount, scriptApproval, scriptApprovalLink, search,
> security, shell, simpleBuildDiscarder, skipDefaultCheckout,
> skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter,
> sourceWildcardFilter, sparseCheckoutPaths, ssh, sshPublicKey,
> sshUserPrivateKey, standard, status, strict, string, stringParam,
> submodule, submoduleOption, suppressAutomaticTriggering,
> suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering, swapSpace, tag, teamFoundation,
> teamSlugFilter, text, textParam, timestamper, timestamperConfig,
> timezone, tmpSpace, toolLocation, triggeredBy, unsecured, untrusted,
> upstream, upstreamDevelopers, user, userIdentity, userOrGroup,
> userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewgit,
> viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, zip] or globals [currentBuild, env,
> params, pipeline, scm]

I thought maybe installing the Multibranch Pipeline Inline Definition Plugin would solve the issue, but it did not. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have Google Cloud Plugin installed on your Jenkins instance?

Comment: I did not. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rahul Sharma figured it out. It is necessary to install the "Google Cloud Build" "Google Deployment Manager Jenkins" plugins in order to get the 'inline' method.